# Normal Map under rotation issue

Tags: graphics, metal, lighting, normals, rotational-matrices

[image]
I have been trying to apply normal maps to a rotating sphere with light shining directing from above the sphere (0,1,0). but lighting does not look correct under rotation as one side of the sphere appears darker and the top side of sphere does not seem lit as expected.

I have tried using a fake normal of (0,0,1) and multiplying that by my TBN matrix to ensure the T,B,N are correct and that all seems to work as expected so I have run of ideas of what the issue might be.

```
if(has_normal_map){
        simd_float3 colour = flatMap.sample(textureSampler, in.tex).rgb;
        simd_float3 tangent = normalize(in.tangent - dot(in.tangent, in.normal) * in.normal);
        simd_float3 bitangent = normalize(cross(in.normal, tangent));
        simd_float3x3 TBN = simd_float3x3(normalize(tangent),bitangent,normalize(in.normal));
        float3 normal = (normalMap.sample(textureSampler, in.tex)).rgb;
        normal = (normal * 2.0 - 1.0);
        normal = normalize(normal);
        //normal = simd_float3(0,0,1);
        normal = normalize(TBN * normal);
        float attenuation = saturate(dot(light_vector,normal));
        return float4(attenuation*colour,1);
        
    }
```

Used fake normal of (0,0,1) to check for the accuracy of TBN matrix and that works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you apply the transpose of the inverse matrix to normals, try that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really follow what you are doing with the tangent, bitangent etc. You might be better off assigning them in the vertex shader like this:

```
.worldNormal = normalMatrix * normal.xyz,
.worldTangent = normalMatrix * vIn.tangent,
.worldBitangent = normalMatrix * vIn.bitangent,
```

Then continuing from `TBN` as you have done.
I also would try negating the `saturate(dot(` => `saturate(-dot(`

Though everybody's code works differently, so it might need some fiddling

Edit: One more thing is to make sure that the light vector accounts for the world position